# two VB6 projects with same bas module - one compiles the other doesnt - 1 line of code

Tags: dll, vb6, file-not-found, lib

I have two projects  - where they both include the same exact file from a peer folder modexample.bas

one project compiles and makes no issue. The other complains about this line inside modexample.bas:

**Declare Function OPEN_SENT Lib "sk32w.dll" () As Integer**

I get the error 53 file not found ""sk32w.dll""

While it doesnt exist in the folder of the project that compiles, I tried putting it in the folder of the project that doesnt  - no help.

I am mystified....any VB6 gurus out there got a moment to ponder this issue?

thanks
Harry

Comment: Such errors are often not literally about the listed file, but some dependency of that file. Dependency Walker ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker ) might help you here.

Comment: ah, OK thanks. I need more tools like that. lost them all in the old XP's crash...thanks Jim!

Comment: by the way found an old thread here in the stack that pointed out I should try a Make and see if that would finish. And it sure enough did! which solved half a problem. Still cant step through on a full compile run...

Comment: If you found another question which is useful, perhaps add a link to it here.

Comment: Unfortunately Dave that was a few days ago. I cant seem to recall the exact wording I gave google when that hit came up at the top. But I'll remember that for the next posting. thanks.